# How to make leukocyte geometry in three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js

Please help to make geometry of leukocyte by three.js.
I suggest that will be with this method THREE.LatheGeometry( points )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create your own Leucocyte 3D Model using Free Modeling Software like Blender. Or You can download Models from the internet, [Free BloodCell Model](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-blood-cell-3d-model/509576). 
If you have your Model in obj or threejs json format you can load them as shown in the loader examples on the threejs example site. [Examples](http://threejs.org/examples/).